# Combining Multiple queries from the same table inrto 1 query

Tags: mariadb, join, query, subquery

I am looking to find a way to achieve the below...

I have tried using `Joins` and `SubQueries` but no joy as yet...

I have a table that keeps track of wins/loses/draws as so

| Date | WLD |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/23 | Win |
| 05/01/23 | Win |
| 12/01/23 | Lose |
| 30/01/23 | Draw |
| 01/02/23 | Lose |
| 02/02/23 | Win |
| 03/02/23 | Win |

Ideally, I want the query to group by month and give a count of wins, loses and draws and a total

| Month | Win | Lose | Draw | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| February | 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 |

I have individial queries for each...

Total

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS Total, MONTHNAME(DateTime) AS Month FROM Table
GROUP BY MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(Month, '%M'))
Order BY DateTime
```

Win

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS Count, MONTHNAME(DateTime) AS Month FROM Table
Where WLE = 'Win'
GROUP BY MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(Month, '%M'))
Order BY DateTime
```

Lose

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS Lose, MONTHNAME(DateTime) AS Month FROM Table
Where WLD = 'Lose'
GROUP BY MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(Month, '%M'))
Order BY DateTime
```

Draw

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS Draw, MONTHNAME(DateTime) AS Month FROM Table
Where WLD = 'Draw'
GROUP BY MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(Month, '%M'))
Order BY DateTime
```

I am looking for a way to combine the above into the one query so that I can thenm plot a chart from the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given data example and expected result doesn't match.

In the expected result there is a total of 5 per January , when in the given table there are 4 values per January.

As per your question.

MySQL supports conditional sum.
For example for  the win query simply use

```
sum(wld = 'Win') as Win
```

It will return 1 per matching values and 0 for non matching.

Final query would be:

```
select MONTHNAME(date_) as 'Month',
       sum(wld = 'Win') as Win,
       sum(wld = 'Lose') as Lose,
       sum(wld = 'Draw') as Draw,
       count(*) as Total
from my_table
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_);
```

Result:

```
Month     Win   Lose    Draw    Total
January    2     1       1       4
February   2     1       0       3
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/9fZQ_YVK

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I think I was overcomplicating things